What is the ES6 module equivalent of requirejs-text for dependencies on text resources?
I use requirejs-text to load a text resource as a dependency of my module.
This makes it so I know the text resource (i.e. the text contents from a url)
is loaded and available by the time my module code that depends on it runs.
If I didn't do this, I would have to asynchronously fetch the resource from inside my module functions, which would force me to leak 'async' all over my API unnecessarily.
How can this be done in the ES6 module world?

a) use top-level await b) use a custom module loader c) use a build tool that includes the text in a js module
